# OCaml - compiling a program as a library

Tags: ocaml

I have an OCaml program(with a main method - it generates an executable) and I want to use it as a library.

I was compiling my program like this: `ocamlc -I someDir -g -unsafe lotsOfCmoFiles -o outputFile` and the program works fine.

Now I'm removing the line that makes it an executable(something like `let _ = ...`) and adding `-a` parameter to compile command: `ocamlc -a -I someDir -g -unsafe lotsOfCmoFiles -o outputFile.cma`

But somehow I can't load generated .cma file with `ocamltop` and `ocamlbrowser` shows an empty list. When I try to load from `ocamltop`:

```
# #load "outputFile.cma";;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Xyz'
```

And I'm 100% sure that xyz.cmo is included in `lotsOfCmoFiles`.

Am I giving some parameter wrong while compiling? Or else, what should I do to load my program in ocamltop ? (I'll use this library in another program, I'm giving ocamltop outputs as an example)

Any helps will be appreciated.

EDIT: So I can finally managed to compile and load it thanks to @cago, now I can load my library, and when I don't remove the main `let _ = ...` line it's automatically run when I load the `.cma`.

But I still can't open any modules. Strangely, this doesn't raise an exception

```
open Main
```

but then when I call a function from module Main:

```
# someFun;;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Main'
```

and `ocamlbrowse` still shows an empty list. now why is that?

EDIT2: I realized `open Main` doesn't fail because I have a Main module in the same folder(even though I didn't explicitly load it). If I move my .cma file somewhere else and load it, it works(ie. main function runs automatically), but now I can't open any modules even though `ocamlobjinfo` shows the modules.

EDIT3: -I doesn't help:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #load "lib.cma";;
ok
# open Lib;;
Error: Unbound module Lib
# 
$ ocaml -I libFolder    
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #load "toylib.cma";;
ok
# open Lib;;
# fun;;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Lib'
```

Comment: Is `lib.cmi` available in the OCaml search path? To use `Lib.fun` in the toplevel, the `.cma` file containing module Lib is not enough...

Answer (score 8):

Some of the cmo in your `lotsOfCmoFiles` need to know the module Xyz. You need to take care of the dependency between your cmo files.

For example:

toto.ml:

```
let x = "toto"
```

titi.ml:

```
let y = Toto.x ^ " titi"

ocamlc -c toto.ml
ocamlc -c titi.ml
ocamlc -a  titi.cmo toto.cmo -o lib.cma (* here is  the probleme *)

# #load "lib.cma"
Error: Reference to undefined global `Toto'
```

Because titi depends on toto so you need to change the order of cmos:

```
ocamlc -a toto.cmo titi.cmo -o lib.cma 

# #load "lib.cma"
# Titi.y;;
 - : string = "toto titi"
```

EDIT:

If your cma is in a subdirectory for example, when you call `ocaml` you need to specify the path:

```
ocaml -I subdir/ (* subdir which contains lib.cma *)

# #load "lib.cma"
# Toto.x;;
- : string = "toto"
```

Comment: What's the output of ocamlobjinfo on the cma file ? I can't reproduce your problem, when I open the module Toto and Titi, I can call the value x and y without any problem.

Comment: that's not my problem, I can already load the .cma file with `#load ...` and loaded file starts running(`let () = ...` part is running automatically) so it works, but I can't call any functions or open any modules

Comment: The cmis is not in the cma file, so you need to tell ocaml where is the cmi files, that's why you need to specify the `-I` when you start the toplevel, this is not related with you `#load "subdir/lib.cma"`

Comment: OK and can you tell me if all the cmis that you need is in `LibFolder` ? You need to tell ocaml every path to the cmis.

Comment: In your last edit, what's the meaning of `fun;;` ? Why don't you load `lib.cma` and just `toylib.cma` ? Because it is the typical behavior of a missing .cma here. Try for instance to `open Unix` (nor error) and then call `Unix.time()` you'll get the same error, but if you add `#load "unix.cma"` and then call again  `Unix.time()` your error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Make sure you don't have any top-level side-effects in the

I was running into this same kind of trouble. My project would build fine, most modules were available, but there was one module that kept triggering `Reference to undefined global`. But it was clear that the module was visible to the system: it was showing up in `utop`'s autocomplete list, along with all of it's values, and I could reference it and import it into other modules.

The problem turned out to be an uncaught exception that was being thrown when that module was loaded. The exception was due to an attempt to load a non-existing file. It wouldn't cause problems during complication, but when the module was actually loaded it was breaking and the exception was being swallowed somewhere before I ever saw it.